# OWIN Facebook Authentication - What does 'context' mean?

Tags: asp.net, facebook, oauth-2.0

I was trying to implement the Facebook Authentication Login in a web-app but there's something I couldn't figure out. I know for some experienced developers out there this is a pretty dumb question but, can anyone explain me this code snippet?:

```
public class FacebookAuthProvider : FacebookAuthenticationProvider
    {
        public override Task Authenticated(FacebookAuthenticatedContext context)
        {
            context.Identity.AddClaim(new Claim("ExternalAccessToken", context.AccessToken));
            return Task.FromResult<object>(null);
        }
    }
```

As far as I know *context* refers to the data in an *HTTP Request*, right? If that so, when we're doing `context.AccessToken` the guide says that that's set by Facebook. How's that even possible? What's the flow there?

It says and I quote:

> As I’mentioned earlier this token is for the external provider and
>   issued by Google or Facebook, after we’ve received it we need to
>   assign it to custom claim named “ExternalAccessToken” so it will be
>   available in the request context for later use.

I didn't get that. 
Can anybody explain, please?
Thanks in advance.

As I said, I know it's a dumb question but I'm the type of person who wanna know how everything works behind the scenes.

-- **EDIT** --
So, Facebook makes the request and sends along an AccessToken. 
Then we store it on that same request context as a claim.
Is that what's happening? If so, then, when is that request context destroyed? (When the request is done, duh) Yea but, when does that request finish? Isn't it after sending the token?

Answer (score 0):

When you authenticate agains an external provider e.g. facebook you redirect your client to the "facebook login page" (not really the login page). There the user enters his credentials and facebook validates them. Then facebook redirects back to your page with an authorization code which you can exchange for an access token.

All of this is done by the Authentication middleware of asp.net when you configure an external authorization provider. I do not know the middleware to well but I assume the Context is transient (per request) but that shouldn't matter to much.

This image is taken from [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/active-directory/develop/active-directory-protocols-oauth-code) where you can read up more on the OAuth 2.0 auth code grant.

[image]